# How to clear all subplots without closing the figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, subplot

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

N = 50

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d')
ax.set_title('Cartesian Plot')

# im = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
# im.set_title('Image')
# im.axis('off')

plt.ion()
plt.show()

for p in range(10):
    Z = np.random.randint(255, size=(N, N, 3))
    A, B, C = Z[:, 0], Z[:, 1], Z[:, 2]
    ax.scatter(A, B, C, c='r', marker='.')
    # im.imshow(Z)

    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(1)
    plt.cla()

plt.ioff()
plt.close()
```

I am trying to plot an image and it's Cartesian plot again and again after it is modified, so I set up this example. This code works if you comment out the image part, then the Cartesian plot is cleared properly. But, if you add the image subplot (uncomment the `im` subplot) than instead of clearing and redrawing all the subplots, they are drawn over each other which is a problem for the plot in the Cartesian space.

Could someone help me? After each iteration of the loop I want both subplots to be cleared and redrawn for the next iteration and so forth.

I would also like the numbers labelling the axis to not show, for the image I did `im.axis('off')` but that only works for the first iteration and than it is set to default.

Comment: To clear an axes `ax`, call `ax.clear()`; if you have several such axes, call that for each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
subplot.cla()  # this clears the data but not the axes
subplot.clf()  #  this clears the data and the axes
```

So in your case, it will be

```
ax.cla()
```

or

```
ax.clf()
```